# Matlab: pass 'who' output on as argument

Tags: matlab, variables

I have written a function that takes the names and values of the input variables and writes them to a file. eg.

```
a = 10;
b = 100;
writevars('file.txt',a,b);
```

gives me a file `file.txt` that contains:

```
\def\a{\num{10}}
\def\b{\num{100}}
```

It would now like to be able to pass on all variables that are found using the `who` command. Eg if `who` returns:

```
a    b    z
```

I would like to be able to use `writevars` as if I called `writers('file.txt', a, b, z)`.

The main problem I have is that writevars makes use of `inputname`... (temporary variables won't work e.g. `writevars('file.txt', 100)` doesn't work since there is no name to be given in the file).

### ANSWER

```
var_names = who;
for i = 1 : length(var_names)
    evalin('caller',['writevars(''file.txt'', ' char(var_names(i)) ' )']);
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [EVALIN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/evalin.html) to run `who` from within `writevars`, e.g.

```
function writevars(filename,varargin)

%# get a list of variable names in the calling workspace and read their values
if isempty(varargin)
   listOfVars = evalin('caller','who');
   values = cell(size(listOfVars));
   for i=1:length(listOfVars)
      values{i} = evalin('caller',listOfVars{i});
   end
else
   %# use inputname to read the variable names into listOfVars
end

%# --- rest of writevars is here ---
```

Comment: Didn't use it from inside writevars, yet `evalin` proved to be useful. See my edit for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It can be used by using the return value of whos command:

```
function GetAllVars
a = 45;
x = 67;    
ff = 156;
z = who();
for i=1:numel(z)
    if ~isequal(z{i},'z')
        fprintf(1,'%s = %f\n',z{i},eval(z{i}));
    end
end
```

Comment: This will not work if the variables are defined in the base workspace.